# Query Netezza to find all tables in views

Tags: netezza

I am trying to recreate the following query in netezza and am struggling:

```
SELECT view_name, Table_Name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE View_Name = '<giveViewName>'
ORDER BY view_name, table_name
```

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Check this [Link](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_command_reference.html) and provide the error that its generated in your current query.

or its this query not returning data ? in that case maybe could be the where statement